# get the UIButton's background image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, uibutton

I need your suggestions: I want to know how to set the UIButton's backgroundImage image in UIImageView.

i.e. If I touch on the button, the button's background image should be set on UIImageView.

Is it possible? If yes then how?

Comment: And its not `click` its `touch` :)

Comment: why did this get downvoted? my upvote took it to 0! The question is very useful - Apple broke their naming convention for this one class only, making it hard to discover the property even exists :(

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
UIImage *image = self.myButton.currentBackgroundImage;
```

[Apple Documentation for UIButton](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton)

Comment: I get return nil for button.currentBackgroundImage. I used UIImage *image = buttonObject. currentBackgroundImage; Please suggest if i m wrong anywhere.